# Laravel Eloquent API Resources: remove "data" key from response (collection)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-eloquent-resource

I've Eloquent API Resource `UserResource`. When I try run something like this code:

```
$users = User::paginate(10);
return UserResource::collection($users);
```

Response will be like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Fatima Conroy",
            "email": "ocie.stark@example.org"
        },
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@example.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can remove `data` key or rename it the get something like this response?

```
[
    {
        "name": "Fatima Conroy",
        "email": "ocie.stark@example.org"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.org"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get all the data just use `->all()`

```
UserResource::collection($users)->all()
```

You can see more in the [official doc about collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-all) where it's explained that using `all()` gets you the the underlying array represented by the collection.

Comment: Cool! I was also able to do `UserResource::collection($users)->values()` to remove string based keys. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to use a custom key instead of data, you may define a $wrap attribute on the resource class:

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Resources;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
    
    class User extends JsonResource
    {
        /**
         * The "data" wrapper that should be applied.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public static $wrap = 'user';
    }
```

If you would like to disable "data" key instead of data, you may define a $wrap = ***null*** attribute on the resource class:

```
<?php
        
        namespace App\Http\Resources;
        
        use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
        
        class User extends JsonResource
        {
            /**
             * The "data" wrapper that should be applied.
             *
             * @var string
             */
            public static $wrap = null;
        }
```

If you would like to disable the wrapping of the outermost resource, you may use the withoutWrapping method on the base resource class. Typically, you should call this method from your AppServiceProvider or another service provider that is loaded on every request to your application:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        JsonResource::withoutWrapping(); // This command removes "data" key from all classes extended from "JsonResource"

        user::withoutWrapping(); // This command removes "data" key from only "user"


    }
}
```

You can also refer to the official link below for more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping